# ngOnChanges not firing at all on my component

Tags: angular, angular12

I am trying to test `ngOnchanges` so I've created a new project and here is my `app.component.ts` and `.html`

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() mydata?: string;
  

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    console.log(changes); // This does not appear in my console

  }

  change() {
    this.mydata = 'some change here';
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>NG Changes</h1>

Changes: {{ mydata | json }}

<button (click)="change()">Change</button>
```

Why I'm I not getting any result from ngOnchanges ... It seems like it's not being fired at all.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngOnChanges` will only be triggered when reference to the `@Input` variables are adjusted by it's *parent* component. At the moment you do don't seem to have any [parent-child component relationship](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs).

Eg.

**Child component (*.ts)**

```js
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `<h1>App child</h1>`
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() mydata?: string;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);
  }
}
```

**Parent component (*.ts)**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  data: any;
}
```

**Parent Template (*.html)**

```html
<app-child [mydata]="data"></app-child>

<hr>
<input #myInput />
<button (mouseup)="data=myInput.value">Push value to data</button>
```

Also note that the `ngOnChanges` would only be triggered if the values changes, so trying to click the button again with the same value in the above example wouldn't trigger it.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2tgj9d?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: So I can't use it to detect a variable change on a single component right?

Comment: No you can't. For that you could use a rudimentary state management using RxJS multi-cast observable like [`Subject`](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject).